# Why is cesium viewer's dataSourceDisplay out of sync in useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, cesiumjs

## Context

In a parent component we're updating a list of points of interest (POI) containing lon/lat coordinates and an id.
We're then passing this list as a prop to a child component wrapping a resium's Viewer component.

In the child component, we're building dynamically a list of Entity component from the list of POIs.
We have a useEffect hook which calls cesium's viewer flyTo method to the first entity every time the list of POI changes.

## Expected

The viewer should fly to the first created entity every time the POI prop changes.

## Observed

Nothing happens

## Investigations

While debugging the calls stack, it seems that at the moment the `flyTo` method is being called in the useEffect callback, the viewer's DataSourceDisplay instance does not contain the new Entities collection when the `getBoundingSphere` method is being called on it. This result in a FAILED state for the entity bounding sphere which makes `updateZoomTarget` return early.

[Demo for repro](https://resium-flight-to-debug.vercel.app/)

[Sources](https://github.com/Mic75/resium-flightTo-debug)